# printing column of array

Tags: arrays, assembly, row, mips

```
    table:  .word  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10
    .word 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
    .word 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
    .word 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
    .word 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50
    .word 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60
    .word 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70
    .word 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80
    .word 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90
    .word 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100

print_str("Enter a column number to print (0-9): ")
li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t0, $v0       # set initial row $t0 to inuput
move $t1, $zero     # set initial col $t1 to 0
li $t4, 4       # set size $t4 to wordsize = 4
li $t3, 10      # set col size $t3 to 10
loopTwo:

    bge $t1, 10, main

    mul $t2, $t0, $t3
    add $t2, $t2, $t1
    mul $t2, $t2, $t4


    lw $a0, table($t2)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall 

        li $a0, 32
        li $v0, 11  
        syscall

        addi $t1, $t1, 1

        j loopTwo
```

I have it working for printing a row of a 2d array. I just need help figuring out how to make it so it prints out a column of an array.

for example
input: 0
output 1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91

Comment: The distance between elements in the same column is the row width.  Add that to stride down a column, instead of just `4` (the element size) to loop across a row.  You don't need any multiplies, i.e. do `position += 40` instead of `position = i * 40`.

Comment: @PeterCordes but dont i need to have the multiples to iterate through the entire indexes for the array?

Comment: No.  This is called a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction optimization; `+` is cheaper / "weaker" than `*`, and a chain of `+` operations can be used instead of independent `*` operations in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_str("Enter a row number to print (0-9): ")
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $t1, $v0     # set initial row $t1 to inuput
  move $t0, $zero       # set initial col $t0 to 0
  li $t4, 4     # set size $t4 to wordsize = 4
  li $t3, 10        # set col size $t3 to 10
  loopTwo:

    bge $t0, 10, main

    mul $t2, $t0, $t3
    add $t2, $t2, $t1
    mul $t2, $t2, $t4


    lw $a0, table($t2)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall 

        li $a0, 32
        li $v0, 11  
        syscall

        addi $t0, $t0, 1
        j loopTwo
```

this made it work